# Local storage won't save my completed list item?

Tags: jquery, local-storage

So I thought I finally figured this out but unfortunately its the last piece of the puzzle.

Basically I have a to-do list and when I mark it as complete it strikes a line through the list item and changes the background-color, it works fine. But when I refresh the page the preferences go away:

```
$("section#todo_list > section.todo_item > span#complete").live("click", function() {
        $(this).parent().css({'text-decoration' : 'line-through', 'background' : '#e1ffff'});
        todo_list = JSON.parse(localStorage.todos)
        item = todo_list[id];  
        localStorage.setItem($(this).parent().attr(item));                                            
    });
```

This is my best guess at the code, I thought that would've done it but no luck, what am I missing?

Comment: You're using the wrong syntax to set in the localStorage

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage.setItem` requires a key and a value, e.g., `setItem(id, $(this).parent().attr(item))`.

I also can't tell what format you're trying to store the data in - it looks like you're reading out an entire list but you save individual items.

As @RPM suggests, also, you should save it as JSON if you're reading it as JSON.

Comment: The entire list is visible but I only need to focus on the one list item that I want to mark, how do I fix that? Also I've added the JSON localStorage.setItem(JSON.strinify($(this).parent().attr(item))); so would I add the id in before the $this still?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you set in the localStorage:

LocalStorage.itemName = "the item";

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.setItem('myKeyName', JSON.strinify($(this).parent().attr(item)));
```

Comment: Gave that a try, still works with the highlighting but it's not saving :S hmm, it must be something in the rest of the code I guess, thankyou :)